# Sqlite query not returning expected values ( Values should be <1000 but are not)

Tags: c#, sqlite

Technology is winforms, using c# and sqlite as my database.  I'm running this query:

```
   string sql6 = "select YYMM,  TotalTrans from t2 where cast(TotalTrans as Real) < 1000.00";
```

I then take the results from the query and populate them into lists, which i then use to populate a listview.

***Problem:** 
The results from column TotalTrans appear to be obviously greater than 1000, as I'm getting a ton of numbers which are even in the 100000s.*

**What I tried to do to fix it:** 
Tried to cast twice because I thought for some reason the TotalTrans column wasn't being converted to float.

```
    string sql6 = "select YYMM, cast(TotalTrans as Real) from t2 where cast(TotalTrans as Real) < 1000.00";
```

However this only made it worse as I got another problem : "Index was out of bounds of Array" in the following code (located in the "reader3["TotalTrans"] part.

```
    string sql6 = "select YYMM, cast(TotalTrans as Real) from t2 where cast(TotalTrans as Real) < 1000.00";
       SQLiteCommand command3 = new SQLiteCommand(sql6, sqlite_conn);


       SQLiteDataReader reader3 = command3.ExecuteReader();

       while (reader3.Read())
       {

           double TotalTrans;


           DateTime yyyymm;
           if (DateTime.TryParse(reader3["YYMM"].ToString(), out yyyymm) && double.TryParse(reader3["TotalTrans"].ToString(), out TotalTrans))
           {
               YYMM.Add(yyyymm);
               TotalTransIrregularities.Add(TotalTrans);
           }
       }
```

**Note:**

This is a side problem, but the main issue is the original problem I posted. The query should return values <1000 but it is obviously not. When I tried to fix it using my approach I got another problem which said the index was out of bounds of the array. Whats the best fix? Thanks

Comment: The side problem about the index out side of the bounds looks like a name problem.  Change the query to `select YYMM, cast(TotalTrans as Real) as TotalTrans ...` and that should fix one problem.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. It can be a problem with delimiters: do your data have thousands separators?

Comment: Good point.  What's the definition of the table itself?

Comment: @LS_dev you were right, I checked the data, it does have 1000s separators but the numbers have no decimals. So I just casted the data to integers instead of real, and voila problem solved. You might want to put your reply as an answer so we can mark this question as successfully answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're converting, I'm going to assume that TotalTrans is a text column and that there's a comma as a thousands separator in the data.  You'll need to remove the comma before converting since SQLite appears to interpret it as a decimal.

```
select YYMM, TotalTrans from t2 where cast(replace(TotalTrans, ',', '') as Real) < 1000.00
```

Removing the conversion from the select statement will get you the value `10,000` back from the DB, but it's OK since `double.TryParse(...)` will interpret the comma as expected (assuming your localization settings specify comma as thousands separator...).

Below is my experimentation with the SQLite commandline:

```
sqlite> create table test2 (value nvarchar(30));
sqlite> insert into test2 (value) values ('10,000');
sqlite> insert into test2 (value) values ('100');
sqlite> insert into test2 (value) values ('15,000');
sqlite> select * from test2;
10,000
100
15,000
sqlite> select cast(value as real) from test2;
10.0
100.0
15.0
sqlite> select cast(replace(value,',','') as real) from test2;
10000.0
100.0
15000.0
sqlite>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your well explained reply but I found out that the text in the column didn't have decimals so I just casted it to int instead of real and the problem is solved

Comment: No worries.  I come here for random real world problems because I enjoy the challenge.  Thanks for the weird ass problem!

Comment: Your testing is pretty cool though ! I'm pretty sure I'm going to be needing this later :)